# Deep Link error

Tags: slack-api

Trying to deep link from a mediawiki uri to a slack channel using

```
slack://channel?team={TEAM_ID}&id={CHANNEL_ID}
```

I'm confident in both TEAM_ID and CHANNEL_ID, and slack app opens, but I get a slack error

```
You tried to perform an action on a team you’re not yet logged into! Sorry, no can do :/
```

I'm actually looking at the target team when I get the error displayed.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's worth noting that the order of the parameters is very important.
It won't work if, for example, you specified `id` first, before `team`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enter the `TEAM_ID` which is completely different from the team name.

Just log in to your Slack team in a browser, open the developer tools and watch the console, you'll see both `USER_ID` and `TEAM_ID` as following:

```
2017/9/4 14:37:52.747  BOOT: Finished first boot 3247 ms after DOM ready
2017/9/4 14:37:52.747  User id: U02A6ESU2, team id: T10A2F3GM
2017/9/4 14:37:54.578  Finished processing users.counts
2017/9/4 14:37:54.578  0 IMs with unreads, 0 total dm_count
```